# How to textfield always returning null when i try to insert into sqflite database Flutter-moor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to insert into a table with the values from a TextFormField but when ever i submit the values of all the field remain null and the insert statement doesn't work cos of that

This is the class containing the form and the insert statement is below as dao.InsertIntoItemList(itemList). its meant to go pop back to a page where it will display the inserted item in a table but i end up with this error

```
I/flutter ( 7352): Inserted new item
E/flutter ( 7352): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: InvalidDataException: Sorry, ItemList(id: null, itemName: null, noOfItems: null, unitPrice: null, checkListId: 1) cannot be used for that because:
E/flutter ( 7352): • itemName: This value was required, but isn't present
E/flutter ( 7352): • noOfItems: This value was required, but isn't present
E/flutter ( 7352): • unitPrice: This value was required, but isn't present
E/flutter ( 7352):
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 7352): #0      VerificationContext.throwIfInvalid[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 7352): #1      InsertStatement._validateIntegrity[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 7352): #2      InsertStatement.insert[39;49m
E/flutter ( 7352): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 7352): #3      ItemListDao.insertItemList[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 7352): #4      _InputNewItemState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #12     PointerRouter.route[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #18     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #21     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:263:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 7352): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:172:5)[39;49m
E/flutter ( 7352):
I/flutter ( 7352): Moor: Sent SELECT * FROM item_lists WHERE check_list_id = ?; with args [1]
I/flutter ( 7352): Moor: Sent SELECT * FROM check_lists; with args []
I/flutter ( 7352): Moor: Sent SELECT * FROM item_lists WHERE check_list_id = ?; with args [1]
```

// The Above is the error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'itemlist.dart';

class EditItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<ItemList> listOfItems;
  final String checkListName;

  const EditItemList({Key key, this.checkListName, this.listOfItems})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditItemListState createState() => _EditItemListState();
}

class _EditItemListState extends State<EditItemList> {
  final key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var itemName;
  var noOfItems;
  var unitPrice;
  final FocusNode _itemNameFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _noOfItemsFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _unitPriceFocus = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.checkListName),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: key,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  focusNode: _itemNameFocus,
                  autofocus: true,
                  validator: (value) {
                    value == ""
                        ? value = "This field can not be empty"
                        : value = null;
                    return value;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    itemName = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name of item',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    hintText: 'eg: apple',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  focusNode: _noOfItemsFocus,
                  autofocus: false,
                  validator: (value) {
                    value.trim().isEmpty
                        ? value = "This field can not be empty"
                        : value = null;
                    return value;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    noOfItems = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Number of items',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    hintText: 'eg: 2',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  focusNode: _unitPriceFocus,
                  autofocus: false,
                  validator: (value) {
                    value.trim().isEmpty
                        ? value = "This field can not be empty"
                        : value = null;
                    return value;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    unitPrice = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Price per item',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    hintText: 'eg: 100',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Add to List'),
                  onPressed: () {
                if (this.key.currentState.validate()) {
                  this.key.currentState.save();
                  itemName = itemNameTextController.text ;
                  noOfItems = noOfItemsTextController.text;
                  unitPrice = unitPriceTextController.text;
                  final dao = Provider.of<ItemListDao>(context); 
                  final itemList = ItemList(
                    id: null,
                    itemName: itemName,
                    noOfItems: noOfItems,
                    unitPrice: unitPrice,
                    checkListId: widget.checkListId,
                  );
                  dao.insertItemList(itemList);
                  debugPrint('Inserted new item');
                  Navigator.pop(context,itemList);
                }
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i handle this error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'", i have tried cast noOfitems as int and unitPrice as int because they are both IntColumn but i still end up with the same error. Please any help atall, thanks

Comment: why dont you use a TextEditingcontroller instead of focusNode ???  and u called by _controller.text

Comment: oh thanks, got a different error this time